# Exclude starting some containers with Docker Compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Currently, I use Docker Compose to start multiple containers in one shot. I have containers started and running already, but while doing `docker-compose up -d`, I just want to exclude some containers while taking other containers up or down.

Answer (score 6):

Use the following to exclude specific services:

```
docker-compose up --scale <service name>=0
```

Comment: Does this build the image anyway without running the container?

Answer (score 4):

Think you have to go the "other way". You can start single containers from your docker-compose.yml via:

```
docker-compose up -d --no-deps ServiceName
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking to exclude some containers because they are not related to the Composition you might be interested in [dobi](http://dnephin.github.io/dobi/).

`dobi` lets you define the images and containers (`run` resources) used to build and run your application. It also has a `compose` resource for starting the Compose project.

So using `dobi` you would only put the containers you want to run together into the `docker-compose.yml`, and the other containers would be just in the `dobi.yml`.